# Count number of tick marks in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

How can I get the number of tick marks that are currently on the x-axis in D3.js?

Basically I want to count how many tick marks are there.

Comment: How about `axis.tickValues().length`? From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues), `axis.tickValues()` will return the current tick values when no argument is passed.

Comment: @mdml No Its not working. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sqY5b/2/ (I have commented alert, you can see that)

Comment: Looking at the JSFiddle, since you don't set `.tickValues()` explicitly, you can just use `xAxis.ticks()` (which returns `10`).

Comment: But that is not true. I want to get no of ticks on the x axis. So I want my result to be 13.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you are using a scale. `xScale.ticks().length` will give you `13`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using a scale to set the tick marks for your x-axis, you can calculate the number of ticks like so:

```
>> xScale.ticks().length;
13
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **D3.js V5 with DC.js**, you can use the following as alternative:

```
chart.on('pretransition', (chart) => {
  const svg = chart.select('svg');
  let totalXAxisTicks = 0;       // Total X Axis Ticks Variable

  // Get Total Number of X Axis Ticks
  svg.selectAll("rect.bar")
    .each(function (data) {
      totalXAxisTicks += 1;      // Will loop through each tick
    })
}
```